Generating filter conditions for dbplyr from dataframe
I have a table that I query in a remote database that I want to create a subset of. This subset is defined by a local dataframe that contains all valid ranges for a column in that data and all valid single numbers.
library(dbplyr)
library(dplyr)
lf <- lazy_frame(a = c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE,FALSE), 
                 b = c(25,70,100,1000),
                 d = c("x", "y", "a", "b"), 
                 con = simulate_odbc())
valid_ranges = data.frame(begin = c(10,30,1000), end = c(25, 70, NA))
col = "b"
tbl_subset = lf %>%
  filter(
    between(.data[[col]],10,25) |
    between(.data[[col]],30,70) |
    .data[[col]] == 1000
  )
tbl_subset

Above is an example of what the tbl_subset should look like given the specific valid ranges.
There is no guarantee on the number of ranges, the specific values of those ranges, and the column to create the subset on. I also can't paste together sql filter conditions, as I use tbl_subset as input for later dbplyr commands. How can I use the valid_ranges table to generate the filter conditions dynamically?
library(purrr)
library(magrittr)
f = valid_ranges %$% map2(value1, value2, function(v1,v2){
  if(!is.na(v2)){
    return(expr(between(.data[[col]], {{v1}},{{v2}})))
  }
  else{
    return(expr(.data[[col]] == {{v1}}))
  }
}) %>%
  reduce(function(x,y){
    return(expr(x | y))
  })
tbl_subset = lf %>%
  filter(!!f)

I've tried something like this, but the multiple levels of indirection and data masking never work quite right.

This might a case where overlaps() could be used. If missing values in end are filled in with begin, it creates an equality constraint.
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(dbplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)

db <- simulate_odbc()

lf <- lazy_frame(a = c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE), 
                 b = c(25, 70, 100, 1000),
                 d = c("x", "y", "a", "b"), 
                 con = db)

valid_ranges <- 
  lazy_frame(begin = c(10, 30, 1000), 
             end = c(25, 70, NA),
             con = db) |>
  mutate(end = coalesce(end, begin))

col <- "b"

tbl_subset <-
  lf |>
  inner_join(valid_ranges,
             join_by(overlaps(x_lower = {{col}}, 
                              x_upper = {{col}},
                              y_lower = begin, 
                              y_upper = end)))
  
tbl_subset
#> <SQL>
#> SELECT `df`.*, `RHS`.*
#> FROM `df`
#> INNER JOIN (
#>   SELECT `begin`, COALESCE(`end`, `begin`) AS `end`
#>   FROM `df`
#> ) AS `RHS`
#>   ON (`df`.`b` <= `RHS`.`end` AND `df`.`b` >= `RHS`.`begin`)

Created on 2024-04-16 with reprex v2.1.0

This is definitely more idiomatic than how I was thinking about doing it! Thank you so much!

I think the best way to do this is via parse_exprs and !!!. This was first demonstrated to me by this answer, adapting to your context below.
For this I will be using the dplyr, rlang, and glue packages:
filter_by_ranges = function(lf, col, valid_ranges){

  clause = ifelse(
    is.na(valid_ranges$end),
    glue("{col} == {valid_ranges$begin}"),
    glue("between({col}, {valid_ranges$begin}, {valid_ranges$end}")
  )

  or_clause = paste(clause, collapse = "|")

  or_clause = parse_exprs(or_clause)

  filter(lf, !!!or_clause)
}

The goal is to create a text string that matches what you would type into the filter function. or_clause should look very similar to the example text in your question.
Once we can generate a suitable text string from the inputs, this is converted from a character string to a command using parse_exprs and !!!.
